# IntelliJ Plugin Development. Class loader exception when start debugging

Tags: kotlin, intellij-plugin

1. I'm creating a Plugin Project using Gradle build system
2. With following **plugin.xml** file content

```html
<idea-plugin>
  <id>com.magicbytes.kotlin-converter-plugin</id>
  <name>Kotlin Converter Gradle</name>
  <vendor email="support@yourcompany.com" url="http://www.yourcompany.com">YourCompany</vendor>

  <description>
    <![CDATA[
    Enter short description for your plugin here.<br>
    <em>most HTML tags may be used</em>
    ]]></description>

  <!-- please see http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/build_number_ranges.html for description -->
  <idea-version since-build="162" />

  <!-- please see http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started/plugin_compatibility.html
         on how to target different products -->
  <!-- uncomment to enable plugin in all products
    <depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>
    -->

  <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
  </extensions>

  <actions>
    <group id="MyPlugin.SampleMenu" text="Greeting" description="Greeting menu">
      <add-to-group group-id="MainMenu" anchor="last" />
      <action id="Myplugin.Textboxes" class="ThirdAction" text="Hello" description="Says hello" />
    </group>
  </actions>
</idea-plugin>
```

3. And Gradle build file content

```js
plugins {
  id 'org.jetbrains.intellij'
  version '0.3.0'
}

group 'com.magicbytes'
version '0.0.1'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

intellij {
  version '2017.3.5'
}

intellij {
  plugins 'kotlin'
}

patchPluginXml {
  changeNotes ""
}
```

The issue I'm running into is the following exception when I'm using *KtVisitor*:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtVisitor PluginClassLoader[com.magicbytes.kotlin-converter-plugin, 0.0.1] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@7591f7
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:63)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 28 mor**
```

Comment: Please replace `id 'org.jetbrains.intellij'` with your real package name, and make sure the running IDE has enabled the Kotlin plugin.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Changing the top line with `id my_plugin_name` doesn't help. It gets the following error when trying to compile **Plugin [id: 'com.magicbytes.kotlin-converter-plugin', version: '0.3.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:**

Comment: Once you use gradle, stop using IDEA build. Run `gradle runIde` to debug.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it did work. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Summarized my comments as an answer. Please accept it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you didn't say how did you run the debug IDE. I assumed you're using IDEA build instead of gradle, and my guess was right. Please give clearer descriptions next time.

Two steps (according to my comments and your reply):

- Change `id 'org.jetbrains.intellij'` to your real package name to avoid conflicts with existing IDEA plugins (possibly the IDEA core is using this id).
- Stop using IDEA build. Instead, use `gradle runIde` command to start a debug IDE.

Comment: Indeed, very helpful, thank you very much for help. Now it does run the plugin without any issue. Regards.